# How to find the number of parameters a ActionMailer method accepts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I want to find how many parameters an `ActionMailer`'s method accepts.

My mailer code:

```
UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup(arg1)
  end
end
```

I tried (in rails console):

```
# NameError: undefined method `UserMailer.signup' for class `Object'
method('UserMailer.signup').arity

# NameError: undefined method `signup' for class `Class'
UserMailer.method('signup').arity

# NoMethodError: private method `new' called for UserMailer:Class
UserMailer.new.method('signup').arity
```

Comment: if you are wondering if it at least takes one parameter, yes it does. see the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UserMailer.instance_method(:signup).arity
```